# XNA Matrix Camera Scale Issue in 2D Game

Tags: matrix, xna, camera

I followed the tutorial on 
http://www.david-amador.com/2009/10/xna-camera-2d-with-zoom-and-rotation/ to achieve a camera that follows my player sprite with zoom in/out functionality.

however, when I zoom in/out the camera seems to either slowly move away from the sprite whilst moving, I don't think I'm setting the position right, but I can't seem to figure out what it needs to be.

Here's some snippets if it helps

```
  if (cam.Follow)
        {
            RectangleF temp = playerBoundingBox;
            cam.Pos = new Vector2(
                (temp.X + temp.Width / 2)*cam.Zoom,
               temp.Y + temp.Height / 2) * cam.Zoom;
        }



    public Matrix get_transformation(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        _transform =
            // Add Zoom
              Matrix.CreateScale(
               new Vector3((_zoom * _zoom * _zoom),
                                 (_zoom * _zoom * _zoom), 0))
            // Add Camera Rotation
             * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(_rotation)
            // Add Camera Position
             * Matrix.CreateTranslation(
                new Vector3((graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width * 0.5f) - _pos.X,
                                 (graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height * 0.5f) - _pos.Y,
                                  0));
        return _transform;
    }
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer through http://xnachat.com/

```
Position = Vector2.Zero;
ScreenPosition = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.ViewPort.Width / 2, GraphicsDevice.ViewPort.Height / 2);
Zoom = Vector2.Zero;
Rotation = 0;
public virtual Matrix ViewTransformationMatrix() 
{ 
    Vector3 matrixRotOrigin = new Vector3(Position, 0); 
    Vector3 matrixScreenPos = new Vector3(ScreenPosition, 0.0f); 

    return Matrix.CreateTranslation(-matrixRotOrigin) * 
        Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom.X, Zoom.Y, 1.0f) * 
        Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) * 
        Matrix.CreateTranslation(matrixScreenPos); 
}
```

would have been the correct matrix to use, for some reason the matrix I posted in my original post cubes the zoom value